# Apply background color to datatables row when expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

When the row is expanded, I want to change the background color of the row, but that doesn't happen all the time. I apply the class, but its not working as well. It only highlights the first row when I expand another row. Is there something I'm doing wrong. My code is below.

```
var table = $('#meterDataTable').DataTable();
var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var row = table.row(tr);

if (row.child.isShown()) {
    // This row is already open - close it
    row.child.hide();
    tr.removeClass('shown');
    tr.removeClass('highlightExpanded');
} else {
    // Open this row
    var elementName = row.data()[0];
    row.child(metersAttributesCache[elementName]).show();
    tr.addClass('highlightExpanded');
    tr.addClass('shown');
    //$('#unitAttributeDataTable').DataTable({ "bFilter": false });
    $('.toggleCheckBox').bootstrapToggle({});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

Your code seems to be missing some parts, it should be in the click event handler attached to `td.details-control`. Also make sure you're using `!important` in your CSS rule for `.highlightExpanded` to make sure it takes precedence.

> **DEMO**

```js
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}
 
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    var table_data = [{"name":"Tiger Nixon","position":"System Architect","salary":"$320,800","start_date":"2011/04/25","office":"Edinburgh","extn":"5421"},{"name":"Garrett Winters","position":"Accountant","salary":"$170,750","start_date":"2011/07/25","office":"Tokyo","extn":"8422"},{"name":"Ashton Cox","position":"Junior Technical Author","salary":"$86,000","start_date":"2009/01/12","office":"San Francisco","extn":"1562"}];
  
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "data": table_data,
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
     
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
            tr.removeClass('highlightExpanded');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
            tr.addClass('highlightExpanded');
        }
    } );

 
} );
```

```css
td.details-control {
    background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/1.10.7/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/1.10.7/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}

tr.highlightExpanded {
  background-color:#F4CCCC !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. Only works when the row below is expanded, then the row above is highlighted. Collapsing the row above, changes the background color of rows below. I'm not sure why one row is affecting other row colors.

Comment: @jamesMakinde, that is the way it was made to work, the row with plus/minus is highlighted. Do you want the child row to be highlighted as well?

Comment: No, just the parent row. I don't know why the back color doesn't stay. Can we chat and perhaps I share my screen?

Comment: @jamesMakinde, please update your question with screenshot(s) on how you want it to appear.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this is how I got it to work if it helps someone else: tr.highlightExpanded td {
     background-color: #9abe1d  !important;
}

Comment: Thanks, just added the CSS class, addClass and removeClass in function and everything works fine. Especially thanks for the live demo.

Comment: if you want to highlight the child row: 
row.child( format(row.data()), 'highlightExpanded' ).show();